# Linq Union, Avoiding null and repeated data

Tags: c#, linq, union

I am trying to write a linq query to merge 2 collections and it is explained below:

```
public class VoteData
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string VoteFunction  {get;set;}
    public string Area {get;set;}
    public string Sector {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string VoterEmail {get; set;}
}

public class DirectoryData
{ 
   public string VoteFunction  {get;set;}
   public string Area {get;set;}
   public string Sector {get;set;}
   public string PrimaryEmail {get;set;}    
   public string VoterEmail {get; set;}

}
```

Linq query:

```
 var result = (from r in voteList select new { r.Email, r.Area, r.Sector, r.VoteFunction }).Union
              (from d in directoryDataList select new { Email = d.PrimaryEmail, d.Area, d.Sector, d.VoteFunction });
```

Now suppose this query returns results like this:

```
No  Email        Area        Sector      VoteFunction  Voter Email
======================================================================
1.  abc@gmail    USA         IT          Sales         voter2@gmail
2.  abc@gmail    Null        IT          Analyst       voter2@gmail
3.  abc@gmail    USA         IT          null          voter2@gmail
4.  abc@gmail    Europe      Tech        null          voter2@gmail
5.  abc@gmail    Europe      Accounts    Analyst       voter2@gmail
6.  abc@gmail    Europe      null        Analyst       voter2@gmail
7.  abc@gmail    USA         IT          null          voter1@gmail
======================================================================
```

There is one more field `VoterEmail`. So basically, I want to count votes per `Area`, `Sector` and `VoteFunction`. 
Now in above result, I want to exclude result no 3 and result no 6. result no 3 because it has area and sector which is also present in result no 1 for same voter, while I still want to keep result no 7 because it has different voter. Similar for result no 6, it has area and voteFunction which is also present in result no 5.

Any solution to this?

Comment: What is the rule for results beating another result. In other words: Why do you want to keep result no 1 and exclude result no 3. Why not vice versa?

Comment: Edited the question.  There would be another field called 'noOfVotes' and this would have same results if combination of region, sector and VoteFunctions are same. So for same voter, result no 1 and 3 would fetch same results for Area and sector.  For VoteFunction, we wouldn't take into account result no 3 as it's VoteFunction is null. Result no 7 has same area and sector but different voter so noOfVotes would change there.

Comment: I think a `GroupBy` _area_, _sector_ and _VoteFunction_ would help you then

Comment: No it doesn't servers my purpose. When I will group by on some Area and find the votes, I get inaccurate results. So let's say, for result 1 and 3, voteCount is 10 and for result 7, vote Count is 20. so while calculating votes for abc@gmail, I get count to 40 (it sums of vote count of result 1, 3 and 7). In result 1 and 3, Area is not null, so I will still get it in group by. What I need is voteCount 30 because I want to eliminate result no 3 because it's area and sector is already covered in result 1.

Comment: Group by on area, sector and vote function and voter email on both classes and then group by both results to make union. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to make groups of items with same values for (Area, Sector, Voter email). If any of these groups contains more than one item, than apparently you have several objects with the same value for (Area, Sector, Voter email), and you want to keep only one of them.

You said you want to exclude no 3 because it has the same value as no 1. Similarly I could say I want to exclude no 1 because it has the same value as no 3. Do you care whether it is 1 or 3, or can I just select any of them?

```
var finalResult = unionResult
    .GroupBy(item => new     // make groups of items with same Area / Sector / VoterEmail
    {
        Area = item.Area,
        Sector = item.Sector,
        VoterEmail = item.VoterEmail,
    });
    // all items in every group have the same Area/Sector/VoterEmail
    .Select (group => group.First()); // from every group take the first one
```